# How to filter useful info to special variable by regexp in TCL?

Tags: regex, tcl

I have follow log from router:

```
LC/0/0/CPU0:Dec 13 20:34:10.487 : netio[262]: %PKT_INFRA-PQMON-6-QUEUE_DROP : Taildrop on XIPC queue 2 owned by arp (jid=126) 
LC/0/2/CPU0:Dec 13 20:34:13.272 : netio[262]: %PKT_INFRA-PQMON-6-QUEUE_DROP : Taildrop on XIPC queue 2 owned by arp (jid=216) 
LC/0/1/CPU0:Dec 13 20:34:15.721 : netio[262]: %PKT_INFRA-PQMON-6-QUEUE_DROP : Taildrop on XIPC queue 2 owned by arp (jid=117)
```

We can check first row for example, **I want to use TCL to filter 0/0/CPU0 to $a; 126 to $b.** Due to those info should variable, so couldn't filter that by string, e.g 2nd row, that change to 0/2/CPU0 and 216.

I only require the TCL to focus a rows, for all rows, I can use loop sentence structure to check each rows by same TCL.

Need your kindly help!

```
% set x {LC/0/0/CPU0:Dec 13 20:34:10.487 : netio[262]: %PKT_INFRA-PQMON-6-QUEUE_DROP : Taildrop on XIPC queue 2 owned by arp (jid=126)}
LC/0/0/CPU0:Dec 13 20:34:10.487 : netio[262]: %PKT_INFRA-PQMON-6-QUEUE_DROP : Taildrop on XIPC queue 2 owned by arp (jid=126)
% 
% set x
LC/0/0/CPU0:Dec 13 20:34:10.487 : netio[262]: %PKT_INFRA-PQMON-6-QUEUE_DROP : Taildrop on XIPC queue 2 owned by arp (jid=126)
% 
% regexp ?
```

Answer (score 1):

After discussed with my friend DaPeng who provide answer:

```
% set x {LC/0/0/CPU0:Dec 13 20:34:10.487 : netio[262]: %PKT_INFRA-PQMON-6-QUEUE_DROP : Taildrop on XIPC queue 2 owned by arp (jid=116)}
LC/0/0/CPU0:Dec 13 20:34:10.487 : netio[262]: %PKT_INFRA-PQMON-6-QUEUE_DROP : Taildrop on XIPC queue 2 owned by arp (jid=116)
%      
% 
% regexp {LC/([0-9]/[0-9]/CPU[0-9]).*\(jid=([0-9]+)\)} $x all location jid
1
% set all
% 
LC/0/0/CPU0:Dec 13 20:34:10.487 : netio[262]: %PKT_INFRA-PQMON-6-QUEUE_DROP : Taildrop on XIPC queue 2 owned by arp (jid=116)
% 
% set location
0/0/CPU0
% 
% set jid
116
```

Comment: That's about right — it's definitely the right tool — though I'd use anchoring (`^` at RE start and `$` at RE end) and `\d` instead of `[0-9]`. I'd also seriously consider whether any of those places where you match a single digit ought to instead be matching multiple digits. It depends on the full scope of possible values, which you probably understand better than us…

Comment: No, I am newer for regexp... if you have good idea, could you kindly paste to here~ that will help more guys~~ in order to check how to work for regexp, I checked "regexp {LC/([0-9]/[0-9]/CPU[0-9]).*jid=([0-9][0-9][0-9]).*} $x all lo jid" that work too.

Comment: Donal is suggesting `regexp {^LC/(\d+/\d+/CPU\d).*\(jid=(\d+)\)$} $x all location jid` -- see http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm